# What data structure should I use to look up a string from an array of possible strings?

Tags: c#, data-structures

If I have the following abstract data structure:

```
"blue", ["sky", "water", "blueberry"]
"green", ["grass", "frog", "lime", "leaf"]
"red", ["blood", "apple", "ruby", "firetruck"]
"purple", ["plum", "petunia"]
```

If I want to retrieve a "key" by passing in one of the matching values in the array, what data structure best supports this operation? I'm looking for a combination of ease-of-use (e.g. clean code) and efficiency.

Since it was brought up: Keys and values are unique, and no two values will be repeated amongst any key (e.g. there is no duplication anywhere).

Here's the way I would do it, but I'm pretty sure it's not the best way, as you're supposed to use a Dictionary by accessing the value by the key, not the other way around.

```
public class ContainerClass
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string[]> Data { get; set; }

    static ContainerClass()
    {
        Data = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
        {
            {"blue", new string[] {"sky", "water", "blueberry"}},
            {"green", new string[] {"grass", "frog", "lime", "leaf"}},
            {"red", new string[] {"blood", "apple", "ruby", "firetruck"}},
            {"purple", new string[] {"plum", "petunia"}}
        };
    }

    public static string GetValue(string lookup)
    {
        foreach(var item in Data)
        {
            if (item.Value.Contains(lookup))
            {
                return item.Key;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
ContainerClass.GetValue("lime"); // Should return 'green'
```

Comment: Can one array value match against multiple keys? For example, could "rainbow" match every colour?

Comment: @BenAaronson No, keys and values are unique, and a key will never be a value, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From just the information you've provided, it seems the easiest solution would be to reverse the dictionary like this:

```
static ContainerClass()
{
    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"sky", "blue"},
        {"water", "blue"},
        {"blueberry", "blue"},
        {"grass", "green"},
        ...
        {"blood", "red"},
        ...
        {"plum", "purple"},
        ...
    };
}
```

So that you can look up values like this:

```
public static string GetValue(string lookup)
{
    string result;
    Data.TryGetValue(lookup, out result);
    return result;
}
```

Of course, you can generate this 'inverted' dictionary from a normal 'forward' dictionary pretty easily with a little Linq:

```
var keyValueDict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
{
    {"blue", new string[] {"sky", "water", "blueberry"}},
    {"green", new string[] {"grass", "frog", "lime", "leaf"}},
    {"red", new string[] {"blood", "apple", "ruby", "firetruck"}},
    {"purple", new string[] {"plum", "petunia"}}
};
var valueKeyDict = keyValueDict 
        .SelectMany(x => x.Value, Tuple.Create)
        .ToDictionary(t => t.Item2, t => t.Item1.Key);
```

This will produce a dictionary that's equivalent to the one specified above.

Comment: Isn't this data duplication, though? I'd like to find a solution where I don't have to repeat keys.

Comment: @SpikeX Well, it's not duplicating the actual keys. The strings are reference types and the compiler will ensure that every string constant of `"blue"` points to the same instance in memory, so it's only duplicating the references to those keys. Even if you generate the strings dynamically, if handle them carefully (or intern them), then it will only duplicate the references to those strings.

Comment: That's a valid point. However, let's say I have 100 values for "blue", and instead of going `"A", "blue"; "B", "blue", ...` and so on, I'd rather just write `"blue", ["A", "B", "C", ...]`, if only from a code maintainability standpoint.

Comment: @SpikeX Sure, you can make that a bit cleaner. Give me a moment to provide a solution for that.

Comment: @SpikeX You could write a function that takes in a `Dictionary<string,string> dictionary, string key, string[] values` that populates the dictionary for you so you  only have the single line in your code and the function does the heavy lifting (I suspect p.s.w.g is implementing something like that right now)

Comment: @SpikeX See my updated answer. (Yep, Scott, you read my mind)

Comment: Nice use of LINQ, I like this. Thanks!